# Superscript 4 not showing up in MFC dialog

Tags: c++, unicode, mfc, superscript

So I'm trying to print `lbf.S²/in⁴` in a mfc label, but it shows-up as `lbf.S²/in4`.

I'm wondering why `²` will display correctly while `⁴` wouldn't.
It's a 32bit project with Unicode character set.

Here's the .rc code

```
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Units"
FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif", 0, 0, 0x0
BEGIN
    CTEXT           "lbf-sec²/ in⁴",IDC_IPS1,77,36,48,8
END
```

Comment: I manually changed the .rc file and changed font to Arial Unicode MS, but it still shows up as a normal 4 in the dialog. In the .rc file it now displays as ⁴.

Comment: The label in your control has a plain '4', not a superscript. Also (correction from earlier comment), the MS Sans Serif font ***does have*** a superscript 4.

Comment: See my above comment, even after changing the .rc file's text, it still shows up incorrectly in the dialog.

Comment: Check that you have `_UNICODE;` and `UNICODE;` defined in your Project's "Properties" -> "Resources" -> "General" -> "Preprocessor Definitions"

Comment: I just added both _UNICODE and UNICODE but the problem still persists!

Comment: Then it's a weird one! I simply cannot reproduce, no matter what I try.

Comment: A [mcve] with an actual superscript 4 would make a lot more sense.  I copy/pasted it  into `hexdump -C` and the `in4` part is plain ASCII.  You should fix your question because as written the obvious answer is that you didn't put a superscript in your .rc file in the first place and everything else is working as intended.

Comment: Is your dialog using `DIALOGEX` or just plain old `DIALOG`? Same for your class in the code - are you deriving from `CDialogEx` or `CDialog`?

Comment: In the .rc it's DIALOGEX and in the class its a CDialog

Comment: Cannot reproduce, it works fine here. Anyway try replacing `"MS Sans Serif"` with `"MS Shell Dlg"` in the .rc file.

Comment: I can't reproduce either. What version of Visual Studio do you use?

Comment: What's the encoding of your .rc file? Try changing it to unicode, if not already. As many others, can't reproduce it either.

Comment: @AdrianMole See my answer below to reproduce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm convinced this has to do with inadvertent changes to the file encoding.

**Recreate as follows:**

1. New dialog based solution.
2. Paste `lbf-sec²/ in⁴` as static text caption
3. Build and run, and all is well.

   [image]
   [image]
4. Open .rc file in Sublime Text editor and try change encoding to Windows-1252. (This is just to try mimic the inadvertent change that Visual Studio somehow *can* do.)
5. Characters are not representable and it falls back to UTF-8 encoding
   [image]
6. Save
7. Visual Studio now refreshes and caption is garbled.

   [image]
8. Paste again `lbf-sec²/ in⁴` as the label caption
9. Build and run, and you see the error

   [image]
10. View .rc file in editor and text has indeed reverted and so has encoding

    [image]

**Caveat**

I'm not saying I know how, why or when the encoding changes, I'm saying it somehow can happen.

**A solution (What works for me)**

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Save .rc file still with incorrect `lbf-sec²/ in4`, and with encoding UTF-8
3. Open Visual Studio
4. Edit the caption to the correct `lbf-sec²/ in⁴`
5. Use context menu in Resource View to save .rc file (don't know if necessary)
6. Close dialog editor window (don't know if necessary)
7. Clean, Rebuild All, run and all is well.

   [image]

---

If I knew how to clear whatever cache the dialog editor uses, then I'd say that would be closer to the *actual* solution.

Comment: how do you suggest so? CP 1252 does not have a superscript 4 character at all. I think it would be right if the .rc was in windows unicode instead.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou I've rephrased my answer to reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that the font you have selected for your dialog box doesn't support the superscript <sup>`4`</sup> and the character is being mapped to the plain `4`. (Many fonts have the superscript <sup>`2`</sup>, as yours does, but other superscript characters are not so widely supported.)

In your resource script, make sure you have a font that includes all characters you want to use ([Arial Unicode MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/arial-unicode-ms) has pretty much everything you're likely to use, and is installed on *most* Windows systems, IIRC), and be sure to include the `DS_SETFONT` style:

```
IDD_MYBOX   DIALOGEX    0, 0, 370, 270                                                                   // 14-JAN-2020
STYLE       DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION     L"My Dialog Box Title"
FONT        10, L"Arial Unicode MS"
{
    //.. dialog controls
}
```

Alternatively, you can explicitly set the font for a given control, but that's a bit more work, as you have to define and load the font into your executable at run-time (I can help you with some code to do this, if you want to go down that path.)

Other fonts that have a good selection of superscript numbers include "Calibri" (my favourite for UIs) and "Arial," but I'm not sure what the licencing and redistribution arrangements for these are.

Comment: I manually changed the .rc file and changed font to Arial Unicode MS, but it still shows up as a normal 4 in the dialog. In the .rc file it now displays as ⁴